# Changing Signer or Draft Envelope DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the embedded sending interface to send DocuSign envelopes.

There might be the case where different senders assess the same envelope through the embedded sending interface. (for example the first user does not send and the second user comes into the application page)

I have tried enabling the Sharing permission but the users are redirected to the Manage Envelopes Inbox page instead of the embedded sending interface.

Any suggestions on how I should go about to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the answer is to back up a step:

Your app can show the documents to the user for approval. If he approves, then he sends the envelope. If he thinks someone else should review/send, then he re-assigns the task to his colleague for her to review/send.

The issue is that once a person starts the sending process, it is tricky to undo it.

I suppose the first person could simply not send and then your app could void the envelope and create a new one for the other person to review/send. But I think that would give a poor UI.

Also, are you sure that you need the senders to use the embedded signing view? It is often a much nicer UX (user experience) if your app can entirely send the envelope on behalf of the signers.

Your app has the most "domain knowledge" of what needs to be sent. Any per-envelope changes can be mediated between the senders and your app. Then your app creates the right envelope and documents.

Comment: Thanks Larry for the suggestions. we do need the embedded sending view for the users to tag additional information (text for the signer) before sending of the envelope. We are deciding between the following options but it is more of a decision for UX experience: 1. voiding the envelope and creating a new one if the original person who loads the page and the eventual person who sends the envelope are different since draft envelopes cannot be transferred 2. send the envelope as the original sender